# Permission Denial: requires android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

Tags: c#, android, .net

I'm trying to detect phone calls in my android app but I receive the following message when receiving a call:

```
08-23 15:16:04.685  Vodafone VFD 600    Warning 850 BroadcastQueue  Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com....LogCalls requires android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE due to sender android (uid 1000)
08-23 15:16:04.549  Vodafone VFD 600    Warning 850 BroadcastQueue  Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com....LogCalls requires android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE due to sender android (uid 1000)
```

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com...." android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <application android:label="myapp" android:icon="@drawable/logo">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And my broadcast receiver:

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new[] {TelephonyManager.ActionPhoneStateChanged,Intent.ActionNewOutgoingCall })]
public class LogCalls : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.Action == TelephonyManager.ActionPhoneStateChanged)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("state changed");
        }
    }
}
```

What I am missing ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, third-party apps are not permitted to acquire the `READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE` permission. See [Privileged Permission Whitelisting](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/perms-whitelist):

> Privileged applications are system applications located in the /system/priv-app directory on the system image. Historically, device implementers had little control over which signature|privileged permissions could be granted to privileged apps. Starting in Android 8.0, implementors can explicitly whitelist privileged apps in the system configuration XML files in the /etc/permissions directory. Apps not explicitly listed in these XML files are not granted privileged permissions.

Secondly, when your app is running on API 23 and above, you'll need to first ask the user to grant you the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission at runtime, as it is considered a "dangerous" permission (see [Permissions Overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#permission-groups)).

You'll need to follow the instructions at [Request App Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) to request the permission from the user at runtime, and only once that permission is granted can your `BroadcastReceiver` receive the intents.

Comment: I added `READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE` because of the error, but ok. Requesting permission works, thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to grant this permission using root? I tried  `pm grant $packageName android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE` , but it doesn't grant it, even though it works fine, for example, for `pm grant $packageName android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS`