# Build.GetSerial() returns unknown on API 29

Tags: android, xamarin, android-10.0

I cant get serial on android 10 device.

I know about everything(permission, runtime permissions, I get serial only after the permission is granted) from here 
[android Build.GetSerial() throwing exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56685799/android-build-getserial-throwing-exception)

My code works on all android versions, except 10

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you follow the official documentation here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#getSerial(), more info on Android 10 changes [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids)

You will notice that starting from Android 10 this method is returning [Build.UNKNOWN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#UNKNOWN). You can't use it to uniquely identify a single device anymore

You need to switch to the "less" persistent version called [Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID)

The only ways to bypass this restriction are:

> 1. Create a system app to be able to get the `READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE` system permission (a normal app can't get this).
> 2. Be registered as a carrier (which requires you to have built the Android ROM)
> 3. Have a custom "work profile" to set your own policies in the device.

As you can imagine, all those options are not meant to be used by standard android app developers

Comment: Tnx for advice with `ANDROID_ID`. I read change notes but still I can't understand there is info that it will always return `UNKNOWN` for Android 10. From doc it should do this if you have `READ_PHONE_STATE ` and you don't have `READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE`.

Comment: The problem is that READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE is a system permission. Only app pre-installed in the system can get it so there is no way to get that permission for third-party apps if you are in a non-rooted device.

Comment: Oh. I see. I read about third-party apps in what doc, but I didn't understand it. Tnx for your help